# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) on printing ar = array("B", ['hello', 'to', 'myuniVerse'])

Tags: python, arrays

```py
from array import *

ar = array("B", ['hello', 'to', 'myuniVerse'])

for i in range(len(ar)):
    print(ar[i])
```

Error:

```
   ar = array("B", ['hello', 'to', 'myuniVerse'])
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Please help with the issue in the above code.

Comment: Because you are creatin array of integers (type code "B") and trying to init it with list of strings... Why do you need to use an array instead of list-type ibject?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`array` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) (emphasis mine):

> A new array whose items are **restricted by typecode**, and initialized from the optional initializer value, which must be a list, a bytes-like object, or iterable over **elements of the appropriate type**.

In other words, if you want to use a Python `array`, you need to specify the right type, which is the first argument that is passed to the array.

It looks like there is [no support for strings in Python `array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), so you might want to use a `list` instead:

```py
ar = ['hello', 'to', 'myuniVerse']

for item in ar:
    print(item)
```

Alternatively, depending on your case, you could consider using a [`pandas.array()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.array.html#pandas-array):

```py
import pandas as pd

ar = pd.array(['hello', 'to', 'myuniVerse'])

for item in ar:
    print(item)
```

Comment: okay thank you so much. That was my understating as well. I was trying to print list of strings using array and i thought i was using wrong type code but it looks like we cant use array to print strings. I would stick with list for this. Thanks again!!